# Inherit Django application (a set of apps)

Tags: django, git, pip, architecture, frameworks

I have an architectural problem.

My team have large Django DRF application (lets name it "portal-backend") combined of set of apps, not installed as a modules but created manually. The apps are: blogs, news, entries, adminapi, gallery, comments, events, ideas, microposts, reactions, moderation, profile, and so on (about 50 apps).

Now I need to make some kind of "inheritance", use this product as a "base" in other team, and allow them to make changes in their nested classes.

1. For example if they need to change class blogs.views.BlogViewSet, they can just inherit it by they own class.
2. The "base" application must be installed with pip (if possible) or pulled from git (it's a single repo)
3. So, the main portal-backend shouldnt be changed in other team, just used as a base and extended by inheritance
4. Ideally my existing application should became some kind of high-level framework to create other portal-backends on the base of it with required modifications and additions on top of it.

What variants I thought about:

1. Split whole application into app-modules, put it into separate git repos, and install each app as a pip module. This method requires lots of work and has a problem that all apps are linked to each other so all modules need to be installed or nothing would work
2. Create some kind of building system, where "base" application git-cloned to specific folder (maybe as a git-submodule) and working app (that developed my other team) imports all the modules from this folder, or patches PYTHONPATH somehow to make imports transparent. Then, it would be possible to import mentioned class BlogViewSet and inherit from it. This looks like some duct-tape-solution, and quite fragile in wolowing development.

What would be your advice?

Comment: Not clear why in option #1 "all apps are linked to each other" - can you please clarify?

Comment: @AviNehama there are tight coupling between apps. Blogs "knows" about Commens, Events know about lots of apps, Moderations knows about all apps where moderations could be done. So, all apps should be installed at once. You cannot install just some of them and work with it (without rewriting absent ones by hand)

Comment: Got it, so my follow-up question is whether each of the inheriting products needs the entire functionality (i.e. all 50 apps) of the base product, or some inheriting products need only a subset of these apps?

Comment: At first iteration, inheriting product should have all the functionality that "base" product has. Later some modules whould be moved out to became a separated micro-services. Lets assume that any inherited product, even if it doesn't need all the functionailty, could just ignore the functionality that it doesnt needed, but has it installed anyway

Comment: I have created a system like this. I have defined some "base"  functionality into a library. Afterwards, I have used that library into another app. In your case, if you can define something that can be considered "base", this approach can work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The solution what I've came to - is to split all the functionality into separated modules and services. It take lots of work, but it's the "right way".